# OpenPulse: Modifying pulse sequence for basic gates

Tags: qiskit, openpulse

I'm trying to familiarise myself with OpenPulse but I'm confused about a few things.

Mainly, I would like to be able to take the pulse sequences that comprise standard gates on an IBMQ device and modify those sequences, but I'm having trouble doing that. If I call "backend.defaults().cmd_def", it brings up a list of Command objects that contain information about each gate's pulse sequence. However, "backend.defaults().cmd_def[i].sequence" is a list of PulseQobjInstructions. Is there a way to convert these lists of PulseQobjInstructions into pulse Schedule objects that operate on the correct channels and that I can simulate?

Additionally, I'm a little confused why each PulseQobjInstruction seemingly contains many more pulses (U-channels) than just the basic rotations that make up a gate. Is it necessary to recalibrate all the U-channels whenever a Drive channel is modified?

Answer (score 1):

Try using backend.defaults().pulse_library, and taking a SamplePulse object from there. If you want the samples of a SamplePulse you can just use my_pulse.samples

Comment: Is backend.defaults().cmd_def and backend.defaults().pulse_library kept updated regularly? Is this the correct place to pull the best calibrated pulses for the standard gates? I am working on a project now and find I get wildly different answers running on OpenQASM vs OpenPulse as well as running the same pulse schedule a week apart. Thanks!